# basename changing the none ascii characters

Tags: php, upload

i am using basename  to get the file , if the file is none ascii characters , the function basename  return uncorrect file name , can any one help  me ?

this the code i am using :

```
$attach1 = basename($_FILES['attach1']['name']);
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a bug:

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62119

You can try something else in this case:

```
$file = $_FILES['attach1']['name'];
$attach1 = end( explode( '/', $file ) );
echo $attach1;
```